# Docker Desktop installation failed

Tags: docker, installation

I tried installing Docker Desktop severally and keep having the error

[image]

I have tried to disable the power services in windows config and also tried versions 3.1.0 and 3.0.0.
Still keep having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

After spending quite some time with the same problem in Docker 4.7.1, I was able to fix this by following a solution suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/684166/failed-to-initialize-all-required-wmi-classes.html). Here what I did.

Open an Admin cmd prompt (not powershell) and navigate to C:>windows\system32\wbem and run the following:

```
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\scecli.dll
regsvr32 /s %systemroot%\system32\userenv.dll
regsvr32 cimwin32.dll
mofcomp cimwin32.mof
mofcomp cimwin32.mfl
mofcomp rsop.mof
mofcomp rsop.mfl
for /f %s in ('dir /b /s *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %s
for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %s
for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mfl') do mofcomp %s
regsvr32 wmisvc.dll
wmiprvse /regserver
```

Reboot your computer after running the commands above.

My problem was that a broken WMI and the commands above should fix it.

Comment: this one worked for me too! tried different old versions of docker and all failed, this fix helped

Comment: `for /f %s in ('dir /b /s *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %s
for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof') do mofcomp %s
for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mfl') do mofcomp %s
`

The above lines did not work for me but after running the other lines Docker Desktop 4.15.10 was able to finish installing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install by deleting file "Docker" on C:/ProgramData/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31392347)

Comment: also look for docker related folders in AppData Local and Roaming - after I renamed them I was able to install docker desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if Windodws is up to date and also be sure your bios virtualazation is enabled.

Have you tried this?

> after successful installation, folders related to the AppData have been moved back overriding existing files (just to restore the settings)https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9780

For your convenience, I hope you'll find solution easily.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue. Try to uncheck **Install required Windows components for WSL 2** when you install Docker Desktop

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. Here is my solution.
First of all you should check your WSL 2 distribution. I ran into an error there that resulted in the exact same errormessage.
First I checked everything in the Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

And tried to run the PowerShell command:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

this resulted in an error and it said that some components (of the OS) are "corrupted" (idk it was in german)

So in other words something in my operating system was wrecked and I didn't know what. I found one page that wanted me to disable multiple services and then reinstall it but it seemed really complicated so I downloaded the Windows 10 update exe

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

and this one pretty much solved my problems. It updated my OS and afterwards I was able to execute the command (Top of my comment) and turned the visualization on.

When this works for you, you can simple follow the steps in the Microsoft doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual
and upgrade to wsl 2.

Installed the Docker Desktop Distribution afterwards and

some restarts later and my Docker Installation worked:
[Installation succeeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0OB8.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556235/4190858)